# Using solr server from another machine

Tags: java, solr, server, external, solrj

I'm a beginner with Solr and by now I achieved to run it in my local machine and index some document. What I need to do next is query by an external Java app or an Android application.

I read about SolrJ which I could use on my client application but I'm not sure how to configure Solr on server-side.

I also learned that since Solr 5.x (I'm currently using 6.3) web cointainers like Tomcat are no longer used, so how do I get an address instead of my "localhost:port" to use within the SolrJ call?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as you already got, [Solr is no more](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar) a web application but you should consider it as a Server, like any other NoSql server.

Solr has its defaults, it usually has HTTP port listening on 8983.

I'll suggest now to focus more on how Solr works (collection, filter and token chains, query parsers, etc.) and how Information Retrieval works in general. Solr guys made the thing very easy, so this is all you need to know to configure your server connection is take care to know what's the ip address and port of your server.

Given that you're planning to use Solr in conjunction with an Android application the HTTP protocol is easiest way to go.

So `8983` is the default port and is used for the server administration (http://localhost:8983/solr) and to connect HTTP Clients.

SolrJ client basically use the HTTP protocol to submit requests. There are exception, for example when Solr is configured in cloud mode, but it's for big company and enterprise configurations.

Here an example that explain how to create your SolrJ 6.3 client `SolrClient` for the collection `my-collection`.

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/my-collection";
SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
```

For example let's compare a simple Solr query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my-collection/select?q=*:*&rows=10
```

in the SolrJ equivalent:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery("*:*");  // means no filters, get everything
solrQuery.setRows(10); // but I want only the first 10 rows
```

So, the `SolrQuery` class is the interface to write most of the queries you can think of.

And there how to submit it:

```
QueryResponse response = solrClient.query(solrQuery); // submit your query
```

Now the query has been submitted and the response usually returns immediately, well it depends from the kind of query you're executing but, I have to say, usually Solr is incredibly fast.

The rest of the code prints the number of documents in your collection
And interate through them.

```
System.out.println(response.getResults().getNumFound()); 
for(SolrDocument d : response.getResults()) {
  System.out.println(d.get("field_name").toString());
}
```

Have a look here at Solr and SolrJ documentation is well written and there are many examples.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but you didn't link anything at the end, did you mean to link something saying "have a look here"? Anyway I had already seen these SolrJ examples but still I can't use localhost in a different machine, for istance the mobile phone where my android application will run. So I guess my problem stays in this urlString mentioned in your example. Making it a standalone application is great but if I can't use a WAR and I have not a static public ip, how do I manage to easly connect with my Solr server?

Comment: So your problem is that you're unable to get the ip address of your Solr instance. That's not a Solr problem, is an network problem. Where have you deployed your instance, AWS?

Comment: I didn't deploy it anywhere. I have installed Solr on my machine and indexed some document, now I want to query this core from an application which is not running on the same machine. Since there is not such a thing like containers with Solr 6, how should I proceed?

Comment: Docker Solr 6 containers exists and are a stable. Have a look at this https://github.com/freedev/solrcloud-zookeeper-docker